# Should the accepted answer really have a green background?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

I find it annoying reading black text on a bright green background when looking at the accepted answer. I thought the big green checkmark was enough to mark which answer has been accepted.

Comment: There is a vague plan of a general redesign of the site AFAIK. Personally, I quite like the aspect you find annoying, though.

Comment: I, for one, have no problems with *that* choice of colors. I might even say that I like it. It offers good contrast, and is easily discernible. But I wouldn't mind if it was changed (as long it isn't something which causes problems).

Comment: I also find annoying that questions with an accepted answer are displayed with the same color (dark green) used for questions with answers, but none of them accepted  (light green). [cstheory.stackexchange.com](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com) is more clear.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi I would say if it is more clear depends on what one wants to stress. The stress here is on distiguishing between question without and answer and questions with an answer, and I think this site does (there might be exceptions if the colors red/green are difficult to distibguish) a better job at *this* then the one you mention (where the stress seems to be on distinguishing accpept or not, which is not that relevant, IMO).

Comment: I like $\color{magenta}{\mbox{magenta}}$

Comment: @WillJagy my eyes are already tired after too much work and SE, and now that! Really, it *hurts.* Well it is not that bad but still. :-)

Comment: @quid, I don't think the word fuchsia works. I do sometimes put color in answers. There is a list of color commands somewhere. I believe one version is six hexadecimal digits, as the #ffffff in the answer CSS code below. Don't actually know what CSS is. They have a really pale blue that might be easier on the eyes than the green they use. Or a paler green.

Comment: @WillJagy oh fuchsia again, I still remember some discussion you had on that in chat. Perhaps we could do some really fancy color theme for MO once.  It was suggested on some occassion we need more gold  on this site. So we might have it in fuchsia and gold. :-)

Comment: @quid, I like it. I believe it turned out that there was a Fuchs for Fuchsian groups and a Fuchs for the flower Fuchsia and the color of that, not things I had known. I was also surprised to learn that there was a Hesse for whom the Hessian matrix was named. Live and learn...

Comment: @WillJagy and presumably it another Hesse that the one that wrote Steppenwolf. I guess we should stop now not to annoy Almo with all the notifications. I would be in chat though; not that that room freezes again.

Answer (score 11):

If it really bothers you, it is trivially easy to inject your own CSS styling onto the site using a userscript. This requires tampermonkey or greasemonkey depending on whether you're using chrome or firefox (or check your browser's userscripting capability). A good resource to start re-coding is [this page](http://somethingididnotknow.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/change-page-styles-with-greasemonkeytampermonkey/). It is as simple as making a new userscript that contains

```
// @match      http://mathoverflow.net/*
```

in the header, with the CSS injector

```
function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css;
    head.appendChild(style);
}

addGlobalStyle('#answers .accepted-answer {background-color: #ffffff;}');
```

Whether this merits changing in a site redesign of small/medium/large/vast scope would depend on how many people feel strongly about this.

Comment: +1 though I think it's seriously a better idea to use jquery, than pure java script. It's an even better idea to just install stylish so that one just needs to code the CSS.

Comment: http://needsmorejquery.com/

Comment: Oops, I didn't know that was an MSO meme, I meant it genuinely.

Comment: @Almo The question has no author?

Comment: @Dimensio1n0 The choice of language is, of course, personal and subject to optimization; this answer is presented as a proof of existence. In other words, you're welcome to edit in a jquery version of the code, or lay off a bit.

Comment: Just for clarity, I only posted the needs more jquery link because it's really funny, and intended no insult to anyone. :)